# How to create sub tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am new in MySQL programming and so my question could seem stupid in some sense.

This is the situation:
I have a weather stations network in which each station sends its data every 5 minutes. Each data row is composed by some columns: id, datetime, temperature, humidity, ...

So, I have 288 lines daily for each station. The stations are 270, so this means that I have about 78k lines/day, 2mln lines/month, 28mln lines/year. Because, among other things, I need to run some queries for downloading the data of specified stations, it is unthinkable to put all the data in a single table.
What I am thinking to do is a schema like this:

DB--> a table for each station (named with its id) --> a subtable for each year.
In this way I would not have more than 100k data in a table.

Now, the question is: is it possible to create such an architecture? Is it convenient or there are some other better ways? I have insufficient experience to answer this question and so I need your help.
Thank you!

Comment: 28 million rows isn't considered large these days. And it's absolutely thinkable to store that in a single table (even 280 million perfectly fine)

Comment: 28million lines may sound huge, but in reality it is not so huge. A well-configured mysql on a decent server should be able to handle that amount of data just fine.

Comment: See [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html)